# How can I disable the Formtastic when I make a form on activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have decimal columns, and since by default, Formtastic doesn't support decimal numbers, I want to disable it in certain controllers, 
Even though I've been looking for the info, I hardly found it so please help me.

- No code, since Formtastic just doesn't support decimal numbers.

Comment: What is your datatype for the decimal columns? To store the decimal value data type should be `float`.

Comment: It’s bigdecimal, in order to calculate money rightfully.

Comment: We use string inputs and add JavaScript to get the behavior we want, eg.
 `f.input :shipping_fee, as: :string, input_html: { class: 'price' }`  You do not want to customize your forms, just do this globally be default?